# How i can can map an large object to an array in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have large object

```
var object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d:4, e:5, f:6, g:7, h:8, i:9, j:10 ...};
var array = [];
```

Output is
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...]

how I can map object to an array in es6 ?
please help me.

Comment: what should be the output?

Comment: and in which order?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the keys, order them and return the value in an array.

```js
var object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d:4, e:5, f:6, g:7, h:8, i:9, j:10};
var array = Object.keys(object).sort().map(k => object[k]);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys()`

```
let arr = Object.keys(obj).map((k) => obj[k])
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which browsers you're wanting to support, you can achieve this using `Object.values()` which is part of [ECMAScript 2017](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.values):

> The `Object.values()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a `for...in` loop...
>
> – [MDN's Documentation on `Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
var
  obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d:4, e:5, f:6, g:7, h:8, i:9, j:10 },
  values = Object.values(obj)
;

console.log(values);
```

Comment: The question was tagged with `ecmascript-6` and specifies `in es6` in the title...

Comment: @trincot I'm well aware; I tagged it. This is why I prefaced my answer by mentioning that this uses a method defined in ECMAScript 2017, in the event OP is able to utilise that as well. Your comment is somewhat moot seeing as the answer you've marked this as a duplicate of asks for a jQuery solution.

Comment: The duplicate asks for *"Is there an better way to convert an object to an array or maybe a function?"* without mentioning jQuery as a *requirement*. I chose that duplicate, since the highest voted answer is a pure JS solution that can serve as answer to the OP's question. I think it is appropriate.

Comment: wow. interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple approach

```js
var object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d:4, e:5, f:6, g:7, h:8, i:9, j:10};
var array = Object.keys( object ).map( function(key){ return object[key] } );
console.log(array);
```