# Make an array of objects from one object

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am a bit lost in my functional programming game.

I have an object like this:

```js
const answers = {1: 'first', 2:'second', 3:'third', 4:'fourth'}
```

I would like to reshape the object into an array of objects like this.

```js
const arrayOfAnswers = [{1:'first'}, {2:'second'}, {3:'third'}, {4:'fourth'}]
```

What would be an easy solution to reach this?

Comment: `const answers = {1: first 2:second: 3:third 4:fourth}` is wrong.

Comment: @PraveenKumar maybe. It's also likely we're just missing the defined variables.

Comment: Hint: Use something like `Object.keys` and map over the array.

Comment: @evolutionxbox no, I meant the commas.

Comment: @PraveenKumar ok. The OP edited it before I opened the question.

Comment: probably already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259082/how-i-can-can-map-an-large-object-to-an-array-in-es6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `Array.prototype.reduce` method.

```js
const answers = {1: 'first', 2:'second', 3:'third', 4:'fourth'};

console.log(Object.entries(answers).reduce((acc, v) => acc.concat({[v[0]]: v[1]}), []));
```

Answer (score 6):

You could map with a destruction for key/value.

```js
var answers = { 1: 'first', 2: 'second', 3: 'third', 4: 'fourth' },
    array = Object.entries(answers).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }));
    
console.log(array);
```

Comment: It's a great answer but the result type (asked by OP) is so strange that it begs the question how one would use such data...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant

```
answers = {1: "first", 2:"second" , 3:"third", 4:"fourth"};
```

Use `Object.entries` and `map`

```
var output = Object.entries(answers).map( s => ({[s[0]]: s[1]}) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using iterating the object's keys. I'll give an ES5 solution, assuming:

1. Others would be giving ES6 solution.
2. You assumed `answers = {1: "first", 2: "second" , 3: "third", 4: "fourth"}`

```js
var answers = {
  1: "first",
  2: "second",
  3: "third",
  4: "fourth"
};
var finalAnswers = [];
var ansKeys = Object.keys(answers);
for (var i = 0; i < ansKeys.length; i++) {
  obj = {};
  obj[ansKeys[i]] = answers[ansKeys[i]];
  finalAnswers.push(obj);
}
console.log(finalAnswers);
```